# how to check for a value in a list of decimal C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, compare, decimal

how to check if a decimal value exists in a list of decimal C#.

I want to achieve the following, but I am looking for right way to compare a decimal value from a list of decimals.

```
decimal value = 100;
List<decimal > Amounts = new List<decimal>() { 20, 30 };
I want to compare if 
Amounts.Any(value)
//do something
else
do something
```

Comment: I am using if(Amounts.Contains(decimal.Parse(stringValue, NumberStyles.Currency)))

Comment: Please don't edit in answers to the question. If you feel the question no longer a question deleting is better choice. If you really feel that no one before you tried to find https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+value+in+list feel free to [edit] the question to clarify how your case is unique (so post can be re-opened) and then provide you answer as *answer* (and not an edit to the question).

Comment: I didnt' downvote, but you're supposed to do some research on your own before asking a question. How to search for  a value in a list in c# is thoroughly covered on the internet already.

Comment: The answer duplicated is specific to Linq, This question can be answered without Linq, using List<T>.Contains(), as @Learner has discovered. With or without Linq, .Contains() is exactly the correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .Find() method from here:

[List.Find(Predicate) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Example:

```
decimal valueToFind = 100;
List<decimal> amounts = new List<decimal>() { 20, 30 };
var result = amounts.Find(x => x == valueToFind);

if (result == 0){
    //not found
}
else if (result == valueToFind){
    //found
}
```

Comment: Hi Troy, how different is your answer to my approach? My approach of using Contains will throw exception? Comparing to the robustness of yours?

Comment: Yours doesnt looks redeable for me I am a layman

Comment: @learner "Find" will return the found item, "Contains" will return a boolean value indicating whether or not the item was found. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, "Contains" may be more useful for you.

Comment: Thank you Troy, good to know it returns the actual item like Intersect. So its ismilar to intersect ist? Only thing intersect is for strings.? Good to know.

Comment: I gave you thumbsup and also tick your answer your intention to help me and your time.

Comment: Downvoting. This approach does not work. Consider the case of searching for the value `0`. The result will be `0` whether that value exists or not.